# Ruby check an apple pem

Tags: ruby, openssl, pem

I wrote this code to check cert.pem status to see if it is revoked or not but it keeps giving me this error does anyone know why, it doesnt work even though it works on shell_script

```
openssl ocsp -issuer ca.pem -cert cert.pem -url 'http://ocsp.apple.com/ocsp03-wwdrg301' -CAfile ca.pem
```

Code:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'openssl'
require 'base64'
require 'test/unit'
extend Test::Unit::Assertions

def load_cert(name)
  OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(File.read(name))
end

subca = load_cert('ca.pem')

cert = load_cert('cert.pem')

cid = OpenSSL::OCSP::CertificateId.new(cert, subca)
request = OpenSSL::OCSP::Request.new.add_certid(cid)

# with post, work


ocsp_uri = URI('http://ocsp.apple.com/ocsp03-wwdrg301')
http_resp = Net::HTTP.post(ocsp_uri, request.to_der, 'Content-Type' => 'application/ocsp-response')

resp = OpenSSL::OCSP::Response.new(http_resp.body)

assert_equal resp.status, OpenSSL::OCSP::RESPONSE_STATUS_SUCCESSFUL
assert resp.basic.is_a? OpenSSL::OCSP::BasicResponse

first_cert_id = resp.basic.status[0][0]
assert first_cert_id.cmp(cid)
assert first_cert_id.cmp_issuer(cid)
assert_equal first_cert_id.serial, cert.serial

resp.basic.responses.each do |resp|
  assert resp.is_a? OpenSSL::OCSP::SingleResponse
  assert resp.check_validity
end

store = OpenSSL::X509::Store.new
store.add_cert(cert)
store.add_cert(subca)

assert resp.basic.verify([], store)
```

ERROR: `x.rb:28:in 'initialize': d2i_OCSP_RESPONSE: nested asn1 error (OpenSSL::OCSP::OCSPError) from x.rb:28:in 'new' from x.rb:28:in '<main>'`